# How to retain mathml tags after transformation?

Tags: mathml

How do I retain mathml tags after the transformation? I'm using this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
```

By the way I'm using the m namespace. After transforming into html, mathml tags are gone. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You are using XSLT so that takes some unspecified input and can generate any XML output. Since you have given no indication of the input or the transformation it is pretty hard to help but as a wild guess

```
<xsl:template match="m:*">
<xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

will copy mathml from the input to the output if templates are applied to the mathml elements.